# Filter elements with specific class in python bs4.element.ResultSet

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

We are scraping the main table on this page - https://www.metacritic.com/browse/albums/release-date/available/date?view=detailed - we have the following to grab the table:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# grab page and soup it
headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36' }
metacritic_url = 'https://www.metacritic.com/browse/albums/release-date/available/date?view=detailed'
metacritic_page = requests.get(metacritic_url, headers=headers)
metacritic_soup = BeautifulSoup(metacritic_page.text, "html.parser")

# extract scores from page
all_trs = metacritic_soup.find_all('tr')
```

every other `tr` element in `all_trs` is an empty `tr` with a class of `spacer`.

```
all_trs[0] # not empty
all_trs[1] # empty tr
```

Type of `all_trs` is `bs4.element.ResultSet`. How can we filter to remove the `tr` elements from `all_trs` that **do** have a class of `spacer`, leaving all other elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Filter while selecting

Just select the `<tr>` that do not have a `class` named `spacer`:

```
metacritic_soup.select('tr:not(.spacer)')
```

#### Filter the result set

If `class` named `spacer` is in every other `<tr>` just do `list slicing` - 2 is the interval, every second:

```
metacritic_soup.select('tr')[::2]
```